# Array-like argument for Devise.friendly_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I know that `Devise.friendly_token(20)` creates a 20-character long password. However, I'm looking at this line:

`Devise.friendly_token[0,20]`

and I don't understand what those parameters mean. What am I looking at, and is this a syntax that appears in other contexts as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets in your expression:

```
Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
# -------------------^----^
```

are being applied to the *return value* of `Devise.friendly_token` so what you have is equivalent to:

```
token = Devise.friendly_token
token[0,20]
```

or:

```
Devise.friendly_token()[0,20]
(Devise.friendly_token)[0,20]
```

Keep in mind that the method-calling-parentheses are often optional in Ruby and almost never used when the method in question is being called without any arguments.

---

BTW, [`Devise.friendly_token`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise.friendly_token) can take zero or one argument:

> `.friendly_token(length = 20) ⇒ Object`
>
> Generate a friendly string randomly to be used as token. By default, length is 20 characters.

So you can say `Devise.friendly_token` to use the default `length` or `Devise.friendly_token(6)` to use a non-default length.